# How can I push to GitHub when it's blocked?

Tags: linux, git, hosts

Right now, https://github.com is blocked with `127.0.0.1 github.com www.github.com` in the `/etc/hosts` file. However, I need to push from git to GitHub. How can I achieve this without editing my hosts file?

Comment: Why do you have a blocking address in your hosts? You can push to an IP address for github if you can find one.

Comment: @icarus My guess? It's not their machine and the person who does own it explicitly doesn't want people to use github.

Comment: Yes, this is a friend's computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `dig github.com` to see what the IP address it resolves to is on your machine and then push using SSH.  For example, if the IP address were 192.0.2.1, then you'd write:

```
$ git push git@192.0.2.1:owner/name.git main
```

You can't push over HTTPS because the hostname you use in the URL controls both the Host header and certificate verification, and those won't work if you use the IP address instead.

Note that you should resolve the IP address on your own each time and you should not add such a hard-coded IP address as a remote.  GitHub, like many sites, uses different IP addresses in different locations and they frequently change, so using what works for someone else may end up sending your traffic halfway around the world, resulting in slow speeds, and any address you use now may become invalid in the near future as GitHub brings different sites online and offline.